# PhantomJS Selenium site does not load

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to create an app which monitors a webpage using phantomjs and selenium but I have found an issue with a certain url as seen in the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver


SITE = "http://www.adidas.com/"


def main():
    print("Building Driver")
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
    print("Driver Created")
    print("Navigating to: "+SITE)
    driver.get(SITE)
    print("Site loaded")
    print("Saving Screenshot")
    driver.save_screenshot("screen.png")
    print("Fetching Current URL")
    print(driver.current_url)
    print("Exiting")
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The program never gets past the line `driver.get(SITE)` How can I make it so that the website will load?

Comment: Did you get any exceptions?

Comment: None just hangs

Comment: I just ran your code verbatim and it successfully captured a screenshot.  Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, PhantomJS 2.1.1, selenium 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is an error in PhantomJS. I would try using either the firefox or the chrome driver instead.

```
from selenium import webdriver

SITE = "http://www.adidas.de"


def main():
    print("Building Driver")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(*path to chrome driver*)
    print("Driver Created")
    print("Navigating to: "+SITE)
    browser.get(SITE)
    print("Site loaded")
    browser.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Creating a headless application would also be possible if that's what you wanted.